# Org-mode timestamps encoding

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, character-encoding

I love org-mode. It's main reason why i switched from vim.
It's really interesting to write reports using Literate Programming.
I try to use TODO, agenda etc. to be more productive.

I was able to make it nice, and clean with org-bullets and other fancy stuff...

...but there is one thing left - encoding. I really want to use UTF-8, so i have something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
(setq utf-translate-cjk-mode nil)
(set-locale-environment "pl_PL.UTF-8")
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(unless (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  (progn
    (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
    (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-mac)))
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
#+END_SRC
```

And it works in most cases. But when I use for example Deadline or Timestamp, and it's **Wednesday** (in polish *Środa*) i got this:

```
DEADLINE: <2016-05-18 \234r.>
```

It should be

```
DEADLINE: <2016-05-18 śr.>
```

Because there is `\234`, Emacs can't save buffer as utf-8.

So. My question is:

- how to setup Emacs to use english locales.
- or how to setup Emacs org-mode to use utf-8 "ś".

I use GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

Answer (score 2):

```
(setq system-time-locale "C")
```

this may generate english date format.

according to this : https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Locales.html#Locales 
locales will affect `format-time-string`

wish can help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I had problems with timestamps in other languages with non-ASCII characters (e.g. Spanish, Chinese), but sometimes I do encounter similar situations to yours in some buffers, especially on Windows. Maybe the encoding of your particular org-mode buffer was incorrect? You can try to run `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system`, choose UTF-8, and see what happens. I was able to display the characters correctly in this way.